# Why is strftime returning a boolean value?

Tags: php, types, php-5.6

i'm trying to implement a module where php 5.6.4 is mandatory and i need to convert the value of the `time()` function to a regular string, the problem is that windows is returning a boolean value from this funciton instead of a string as it should...

here's the code

```php
<?php
$todays_date = strftime("%u:%d:%m:%Y:%H:%M", time());
echo(gettype($todays_date));
?>
```

And the output:

`boolean`

I tested this same code on linux and it seems to be working just fine but windows is a mandatory use as well

EDIT:
the boolean's value is `false`

Comment: *The function returns false if format is empty, contains unsupported conversion specifiers, or if the length of the returned string would be greater than 4095.* https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#refsect1-function.strftime-returnvalues

Comment: Yeah, I already read that part of the documentation but all of the string modifiers used in the format string are supposedly supported on the windows implementation.

Comment: Other than that, I cannot reproduce: https://3v4l.org/M6nl5 are you sure you didn't fixed it in the minimal version your are producing here

Comment: yep, ```<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Monterrey');
print(time());
$fecha_actual = strftime("%u:%d:%m:%Y:%H:%M", time());

echo(gettype($fecha_actual));

if($fecha_actual){
    print("A");
}
else{
    print("B");
}
?>```

That's the exact code im using for testing, and this is one of the outputs i got

```1613759771booleanB```

Comment: Got the exact same, this is working, it only start to fails on really early versions of 5.x where `date_default_timezone_set` was not a function yet, so this is not relevant. What I would test if I were you: rebuild the `format` bit by bit: `echo gettype(strftime("%u", time())));` then `echo gettype(strftime("%u:%d", time())));`, ... up until it fails, and feed this into your question if you don't find the issue along the way.

Comment: Windows does not support the %k format for strftime.

Comment: I fixed the issue by ditching strftime() in favor of date(). I even switched %k moddifier to %H modiffier as suggested in the microsoft's documentation of strftime() (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160) but didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I suggest [testing the tokens individually](https://3v4l.org/m0cG3) to see which ones are not supported in your version of PHP + Windows instead of guessing at each. `var_dump([strftime('%u', time()), strftime('%d', time()), strftime('%m', time()), strftime('%Y', time()),  strftime('%H', time()), strftime('%M', time())]);`.